# How to decompose 2d transform matrix and how to composite them back

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication, matrix-decomposition

I am writing some vector shape transform demo , and I am stucked:

There is a transform matrix datas got from some shape :

```
matrix = [3.23891, -0.87126, 246.73324, 1.07431, 0.86589, 169.21047, 0, 0, 1]
```

Then I use a `decomposeMatrix` method (comes from here : https://frederic-wang.fr/decomposition-of-2d-transform-matrices.html) to split the matrix to `translation`,`scale`,`rotation`,`skew` , I make these values recorded in a new `shape` class , when I refresh the canvas , this `shape` instance will invoke a method to calculate its local matrix via these pose values, I thought it will return a almost same matrix with the matrix decomposed before, but not.

From the matrix I got there datas:

```
rotation: 0.32026899072894127
scale: {x: 3.412432386032404, y: 1.0961547154147515}
skew: {x: -0.16104628632010806, y: 0}
translation: {x: 246.73324584960938, y: 169.21047973632812}
```

I compared these datas with "https://frederic-wang.fr/decomposition-of-2d-transform-matrices.html" web page , they are same , and the web page demo can get the correct image pose result I expected.

So I tought maybe my matrix multiply method was wrong?

The matrix concat order is :

```
Local = Translate * Rotate * Skew * Scale
```

And I tried other concat order , such like `T * R * Sc * Sk`, but I still can not get correct result.

Dear family , can you help me to resolve this problem? 比心!

Comment: BTW, the matrix datas order is like this : `1,0,tx,0,1,ty,0,0,1`=>  'a,b,c,d,e,f,0,0,1'. My transform matrix order is `a,d,b,e,c,f ` => rotate : `cos, sin, -sin, cos, 0, 0` , translate: `1, 0, 0, 1, x, y` , scale : `sx, 0, 0, sy, 0, 0`, skew: `1, tanx, tany, 1, 0, 0` , are they incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks family! I resolve it! skew transform was wrong and the order should be Translate * Rotate * Scale * Skew